# Midrash that Yosef sinned first

Tags: yosef, genesis-bereishith

Can someone point me to a midrash that says that Yosef actually started sinning with Eshet Potiphar but then stopped?

Comment: Sotah 36B explains that he released his semen through his fingers. Is that what you referring to?

Comment: @Chatzkel no not that one. I remember hearing somewhere that like there’s a midrash that Yosef was mid-act and then he stopped. Ring any bells or did I make it up?

Comment: I don’t think I recall anyone saying he actually started. The Gemara there says he intended to do it. The yalkut says כיון שבא ליזקק לה בא הקב"ה בדמות אביו ונתקררה אמתו שנאמר ותשב באיתן קשתו

Comment: @Chatzkel so maybe that’s what I’m referring to, thanks

Comment: Rashi to the passuk says that he went in to sin and stopped himself.